# Upgrading Ubuntu Server to a recent version would update PHP too? This result in any problems?

Tags: ubuntu, php, update

I use Ubuntu Server 10.04 and PHP 5.3.2, if I upgrade the server to a more recent version, the PHP would update too? Would this process result in some problem in the settings of PHP, like previously installed extensions?

Comment: There is no way for *us* to know what will happen to ***YOUR*** environment. Perform a test on your development server. (You do have a development server, right? If not now is a really good time to set one up...)

Answer (score 1):

- Check Release Notes for the newer Ubuntu version you want to upgrade to
- Most probably the PHP version will be a higher one than you have now; google for upgrade instructions (if neccessary)
- If you are running a production system, first run tests on a different (test) system
- If needed, create a backup before upgrading so that you can easily roll back in case of any issues

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "No". The long answer is that there would be no issues since the extensions would also get updated. By the way the settings file is not overwritten.